# Why is my API output results are being trimmed with ellipses

Tags: api, axios, rapidapi

I am using a Google search API from rapidapi website. Whenever I enter my inputs I receive output as trimmed one. Is there any way to resolve this?
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onHlq.png)

I tried searching for max tokens for that API but unfortunately there was not a column for that

Answer (score 0):

This just has to do with the display of RapidAPI / console. Try array[0].title and you will see the whole thing.

Comment: I tried doing that but I am still getting elipses

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).